# I am getting RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded error in Javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion, while-loop, dynamic-programming, callstack

I am trying to solve a problem of leetcode through recursion but I am getting an error saying `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` maybe I am doing something wrong.

Problem:

Write an algorithm to determine if a number n is happy.

A happy number is a number defined by the following process:

Starting with any positive integer, replace the number by the sum of the squares of its digits.

Repeat the process until the number equals 1 (where it will stay), or it loops endlessly in a cycle which does not include 1.
Those numbers for which this process ends in 1 are happy.

Return true if `n` is a happy number, and `false` if not.

```
Example 1:

Input: n = 19
Output: true
Explanation:
12 + 92 = 82
82 + 22 = 68
62 + 82 = 100
12 + 02 + 02 = 1
Example 2:

Input: n = 2
Output: false
```

My Code:

```
var isHappy = function(n) {
    if(n.length<2) return false
    
    
    var fn=(n)=>{
        let i=0; 
        let sum=0;
    while(i<n.length){
     sum=sum+Math.pow(n[n.length-1-i],2);
     i++;   
    }
    while(sum!==1){
     //console.log(sum)
    fn(sum);
    }
 if(sum === 1) return true
    }
    fn(n)
};
```

PS: I don't need a solution for this problem. I want to find out why my code isn't working and What I am doing wrong. And, What changes should I make so that it works fine.

[Link](https://leetcode.com/problems/happy-number/) to the above problem.

Comment: In your `while` loop you check the value of `sum` but never actually change it anywhere!

Comment: @JoachimSauer What changes should I make in my code then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you wrote yourself, *"Repeat the process until the number equals 1 (where it will stay), or **it loops endlessly** in a cycle"*.

In your implementation, `fn` calls itself infinitely. In the process, the javascript virtual machine creates a fonction context in memory at each iteration. This can be done up to a certain times after which the error `Maximum call stack size exceeded` throws.

***What I am doing wrong?***

You return true when you find a happy number, but you never return false otherwise. Add a condition to detect unhappy numbers (detect a cycle) and return false in that case.

Edit: here is an example implementation:

```js
var isHappy = function(n) {
    if(n.length<2) return false
    
    // placeholder to store already called values
    const calledValues= new Set()
    
    var fn=(n)=>{
        let i=0; 
        let sum=0;
        
      if (calledValues.has(n))
        // cycle detected!
        return false;
      
      calledValues.add(n);
      
      while(i<n.length){
        sum=sum+Math.pow(n[n.length-1-i],2);
        i++;   
      }
 
      if (sum !== 1)
        return fn(sum.toString());
      else
        // sum === 1, number is happy!
        return true
    }
    
    // make sure to pass a string to fn
    return fn(n.toString());
};

(new Array(20)).fill().map((_,i)=>10+i)
.forEach(n=> console.log(n, "is happy?", isHappy(n)));
```

Comment: How can I add a condition to detect unhappy numbers? What changes should I make in my code?

Comment: You need to detect cycles, i.e. you need to detect if you are calling fn with a value n for which you have _already_ called fn.

Comment: But why are we converting numbers to strings?

Comment: Because the while loop assumes n to be a string: this is so to be able to "split" n into its digits (e.g. a number has no length property).

Answer (score 1):

```
Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

This error occurs when functions call other functions too many times. In this case, your function calls itself recursively with no end, should the number be an "unhappy" one.

Consider adding into your function something which allows you to tell if the process loops endlessly.

> Consider using arguments/arrays to store what numbers have already turned up.

Comment: But I am checking the value of `sum` in the `while` loop and if it `sum === 1` then it should end the loop.

Comment: What changes should I make in my code?

Comment: @HarshMishra, I believe Vincent gave a good example. const calledValues= new Set() creates a set of all the numbers that have already turned up. if (calledValues.has(n)) ends the program and returns false if a number shows up twice, indicating a loop.